# Set the container as the child of the bottom nav bar but there is a space between the bottom of the screen and the nav bar now

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

[image]

So i created my own bottom app bar following a tutorial. However, there is a white space between the bottom nav bar and the bottom of the screen. I coloured this space in white to show it. How can i make my container the actual nav bar and hide that space?

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class bottomAppBar extends StatelessWidget {
  const bottomAppBar({
    Key? key,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BottomAppBar(
      color: Colors.white,
      child: Container(
        color: Color(0xFF313131).withOpacity(0.7),
        height: 50,
        width: double.maxFinite,
        child: Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
          children: [
            IconButton(
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/');
              },
              icon: Icon(
                Icons.home,
                color: Colors.white,
              ),
            ),
            IconButton(
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/discover');
              },
              icon: Icon(
                Icons.search,
                color: Colors.white,
              ),
            ),
            IconButton(
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/mybookings');
              },
              icon: Icon(
                Icons.hello,
                color: Colors.white,
              ),
            ),
            IconButton(
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/user');
              },
              icon: Icon(
                Icons.person,
                color: Colors.white,
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: try to set your Scaffold backgroundColor to Color(0xFF313131).withOpacity(0.7)

Answer (score 1):

I'm reposting this comment by Jim as an answer so that people notice it:

"try to set your Scaffold backgroundColor to Color(0xFF313131).withOpacity(0.7)" - Jim

Try Setting a background color to your scaffold according to the app theme you're using.

Answer (score 0):

Did you put [SafeArea](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/SafeArea-class.html) in your Scaffold? It can happen when you use SafeArea widget and your screen is not a rectangle, it will create padding on the top and bottom of the screen.

Comment: No i have not used the safe area widget and it is shown like this on other screens too where i have nothing but the bottom nav bar